# any open source libraries to extract photo/video attachments from email and/or MMS which take care of "hundreds" of test cases

Tags: php, email, parsing, mms, attachment

I want to allow users to upload photos and videos with their mobile phone by sending the photo/video to an email address.  Cal Henderson in "Building Scalable Web Sites" mentions that Flickr has "hundreds" of test cases to deal with the fact that "Wireless Carriers Hate You".

Are there any open source projects/libraries that try to address the quirks of different wireless carriers?

So far I have come across:

- mms2r (seems most promising)
- http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4015.html
- http://www.nerdydork.com/download-pop3imap-email-attachments-with-php.html
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html

Any others?  I would prefer php, but it's not required.

EDIT: oh, and any keyword suggestions to search for would be helpful.  My google-fu seems to be returning a lot of not quite relevant results.

Comment: After reading your question again I do know of something like Flickr but for Video: 
http://vimeo.com/help/faq#mobile_uploads
I don't think this is what your looking for just an option I would throw out there.

Comment: <username>@up.vimeo.com sorry I don't think the link works but it's in the FAQ, just search for email

Answer (score 0):

Wireless Carriers are cracking down on the [Carrier gateway(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) they offer ([SMS/MMS Transit list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_SMS_transit)). As listed on the transit list you will see something like this for MMS number@mms.att.net but this is a hit or miss since the Carriers are cracking down on what can be sent for free. You could go the way of a [Mobile Messaging Aggregator](http://www.openmarket.com/) as the Carriers are wanting end users to use [Short Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) instead of the Gateways.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/